# Different type of imaging techniques in kognitio

Tags: kognitio-wx2, kognitio

Can anyone please explain me what are all the imaging techniques available in kognitio.

Would be great if you cover the below techniques.

1) Replicated

2) REPLICATED PARTITION IMAGE BY (column_name)

3) HASHED ON (column_name) PARTITION IMAGE BY (column_name)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have four different Imaging options in WX2
Random – even round robin distribution (default)
Hashed – placed onto RAM stores according to key
Partial Hashed – as hashed but handles skewing attributes
Replicated – complete copy on each RAM Store

Replication puts a copy of the image on every RAM Store. It can be costly in terms of RAM and redistribution time. Good for small lookup/dimension tables
It cannot be fragmented. It is required for Theta joins. Replication is per RAM Store and not per node.

Hashing distributes the rows of a table or view image across the RAM Stores. It is dependent upon the value of one or more columns. It is good for joining large tables – hash on common key. It may lead to skewing. The number of distinct values is less than number of RAM Stores. One or two values greatly exceed the others in frequency. Partial distribution may be used to neutralize value skew

Partial hashing is a mechanism to handle joins when a large table is severely skewed on key column(s). It is an alternative to straightforward hashing. Types are Partial hashed/random RAM stores and Partial hashed/replicated across RAM stores

Comment: Note that you don't need to explicitly replicate an object to use it in theta joins - the optimiser will replicate it if required, after having first applied local predicates to filter out rows that are not required. Also, note that the Kognitio Guide refers to other imaging choices beyond how individual rows are distributed to ram stores, including partitioning,  vertical/horizontal fragmentation, compressed images, sorted images, and prejoins.

Comment: Thanks for the info @mc110

Answer (score 2):

The Kognitio community forum article [here](http://www.kognitio.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3) has links to all the latest documentation.

In particular, chapter 2 of the Kognitio Guide covers the various table and view image options that exist.

The ones referred to in the original question are:

1. **replicated** - here a copy of the object is placed in every ram store process. This is typically used for dimension objects to allow them to be joined to large objects, regardless of whether those objects are randomly distributed or hashed.
2. **partitioned** (deciding whether to partition or not is independent of whether you are replicating/randomising/hashing) - this allows the ram store to partition on an attribute. The main benefit is that partitions can be eliminated on scans, reducing the amount of data processed. Note the further comments in the documentation on partitioning though.
3. **hashed** - hashing on an attribute allows data to be distributed according to that attribute value. For example, in a retail example you might hash the customer table by customer_id, and do the same with the transaction table, then any given transaction is located on the same ram store as the relevant customer record. Note that this distribution is prone to skewing; so consult the documentation for details on using partial distributions to defeat skew.